# Gmail Notifier for Lubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, email, gmail, mail-notification

I am using Lubuntu Xenial and I would like to install a lightweight email notifier. I thought it would be easy to find a notifier with the following features:

1. Lightweight, use very little memory and cpu (no heavy email clients, browser extensions, java clients etc.)
2. Should have an icon in the tray (changing color when new email arrives)
3. Should work with Gmail
4. Should give a new email list on a popup
5. Should have email preview popup/tooltip
6. Should have "mark as read"

I have used checkgmail until a couple of months ago, which did all these. I kept patching it, but after the last Google protocol update I could no longer fix it.

I tried gnubiff, but it seems so outdated (no mark as read and previews only plaintext emails, which are a minority in my mailbox)

It seems that all notifiers are unmaintained and no longer compatible with newer (L)ubuntu versions. I am surprised at not being able to find a good lightweight email notifier. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity Mail now supports LXDE.

https://tari.in/www/software/unitymail/

Comment: Yes, I ended up using this. Not as good, but better than nothing.